# NSIS Edit not extracting all files and folders if package size is large

Tags: installation, nsis, packaging

I created one package installer using nsis edit but while installing the package, it extracts only few folders at installation directory. All the files and folder that I added into the package at the time of creation of package were not extarcted in the installation directory. Packaging was done successfully and compilation was also successful as there was no error during these processes.Total size of my files and folders that I added into the package is around 900 MB and the package(.exe) I received is of 250 MB.

I observed one thing here is that If I include files and folder upto 150 MB then it does not give my any issues. It extracts all the files and folders that I added into package. So till now my observation says that NSIS does not support packaging of larger size(I've seen it works fine upto 150 MB). Is there any such limitation with NSIS free version. I'm currently using HM NSI Edit 2.0.3 and NSIS  3.03.

Below is the .nsi script for my package.

```
   ; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.

; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!define PRODUCT_NAME "setup11"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.0"
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "My company, Inc."
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "http://www.mycompany.com"
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\jabswitch.exe"

SetCompressor lzma

; MUI 1.67 compatible ------
!include "MUI.nsh"

; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-install.ico"

; Welcome page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
; License page
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Desktop\Package Installer\license.txt"
; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; Finish page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; Reserve files
!insertmacro MUI_RESERVEFILE_INSTALLOPTIONS

; MUI end ------

Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
OutFile "Setup11.exe"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\setup11"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""
ShowInstDetails show

Section "MainSection" SEC01
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin"
  SetOverwrite try
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\awt.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\axbridge.dll"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\client"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\client\Xusage.txt"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\dcpr.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\decora-sse.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\deploy.dll"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\dtplugin"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\dtplugin\deployJava1.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\dtplugin\npdeployJava1.dll"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\dt_shmem.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\dt_socket.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\eula.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\fontmanager.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\fxplugins.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\glass.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\glib-lite.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\gstreamer-lite.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\hprof.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\installer.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\instrument.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\j2pcsc.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\j2pkcs11.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jaas_nt.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jabswitch.exe"
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\setup11"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\setup11\setup11.lnk" "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jabswitch.exe"
  CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\setup11.lnk" "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jabswitch.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\java-rmi.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\java.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\java.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\JavaAccessBridge-32.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\JavaAccessBridge.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\javacpl.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\javafx-font.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\javafx-iio.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\javaws.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\java_crw_demo.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jawt.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\JAWTAccessBridge-32.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\JAWTAccessBridge.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\JdbcOdbc.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jdwp.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jfr.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jfxmedia.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jfxwebkit.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jli.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jp2iexp.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jp2launcher.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jp2native.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jp2ssv.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jpeg.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jpicom.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jpiexp.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jpinscp.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jpioji.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jpishare.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jqs.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jsdt.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jsound.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jsoundds.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\kcms.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\keytool.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\kinit.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\klist.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\ktab.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\libxml2.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\libxslt.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\management.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\mlib_image.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\net.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\nio.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\npjpi170_80.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\npoji610.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\npt.dll"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\orbd.exe"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\pack200.exe"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\lib"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\lib\jsoup-1.9.2.jar"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\lib\ojdbc6.jar"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\FetchLogs\LogsUtility.jar"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\lib"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\lib\AutomationFramework.jar"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\lib\ini4j-0.5.4.jar"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\lib\javafx-dialogs-0.0.4.jar"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\RFTjar.jar"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\SAPDriver.vbs"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\TestAutomationWizard.jar"
  File "C:\Users\meenal.jain\Downloads\Workspace\ITAF\Scripts\WebserviceTPA.vbs"
SectionEnd

Section -AdditionalIcons
  WriteIniStr "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.url" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\setup11\Website.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.url"
SectionEnd

Section -Post
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$INSTDIR\FetchLogs\jre7\bin\jabswitch.exe"
SectionEnd

RequestExecutionLevel user
```

There was not any error while i compiled this .nsi file but still all files and folders are not getting extracted.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS (all v2 and v3 versions) are limited to 2 GiB of compressed data. Your source files may be larger than this as long as the final compressed result fits in 2 GiB.

Without any example code it is hard to tell what is going on.

Try something simple like this:

```
InstallDir "$Temp\InstallTest"

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /r "c:\myFiles" ; Replace the path with the location of your real files
File /r "x:\stuff\myOtherFiles"
SectionEnd
```

There is a 3rd-party version of NSIS that supports 4 GiB installers if you really need it.

Comment: but my source files size is 900 MB only. It is not even 2GB then why it is not extracting all files and folders.

Comment: @MeenalJain There is no way to know because you have not posted any example code nor told us about any error messages.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the script code of my .nsi file and there was no error message while I compiled .nsi script but still it's not extracting all files and folders.Could you please check Whether I'm missing something in this script or what else possibility may be there which is causing this issue.